# Are reduction potential and stability related?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, stability

Consider the half reactions:

\begin{align}
\ce{Na^+ +  e- &->  Na} &\quad E^\circ &= -\pu{2.71 V} \tag{1}\\
\ce{Cu^2+ + 2 e- &->  Cu} &\quad E^\circ &= \pu{+0.34 V} \tag{2}
\end{align}

Can I say that $\ce{Na+}$ is more stable than $\ce{Na}$ since $\ce{Na+}$ has negative potential? If so, can I also say that $\ce{Cu^2+}$ is less stable than $\ce{Cu}$ so $\ce{Cu^2+}$ has a positive potential?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that reduction potentials do not have any meaning by themselves. They are measured against a hydrogen cell to which arbitrarily we assign the value $E^\circ=0$. You can compare between different potentials. For example, in your case, you could say that that $\ce{Cu^2+}$ has a greater tendency to be reduced than $\ce{Na^+}$  because its reduction potential is more positive. However, I do not think the potential itself tells you anything with regard to the stability (and, in any case, what do you mean by that) of the species involved in a particular half reaction.